# How to remove api and scope from GoogleApiClient in Android?

Tags: android, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

In my app some Google APIs are optional. (In this case the Games API.)

In my settings activity, the user can choose to not signin into Google Games. There I call

```
Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
googleApiClient.disconnect();
googleApiClient = createGoogleApiClientWithoutGames();
googleApiClient.connect();
```

`createGoogleApiClientWithoutGames` method creates a new GoogleApiClient that does not use the Games API and corresponding scopes.

1. Is this the correct way to remove api and scope from the client?
2. How can I make sure that the googleApiClient of other activities (that are not yet destroyed) don't use the Games API? Currently, when returning from the settings activity, the client is connecting in `onStart()` using the current client configuration (with Games). Send a local broadcast message and recreate the client as well?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the question is for Android

Comment: I have created a repo at github with a simple app that shows the problem: https://github.com/friedger/google-api-client-example/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

I am using a status variable to check in `onStart()` whether the current client in the MainActivity uses the correct apis. If not I recreate it before connecting.

The full source code is available at https://github.com/friedger/google-api-client-example